# Can I close underlying outputstream and let the decorator BufferedOutputStream unclosed

Tags: java, memory-management, outputstream

I have multiple implementations of a

```
 void convert(List< InputStream > list, OutputStream os)
```

method.

The given resources may be reused and are so not released by the method implementations. However I would like to decorate the given output stream with a BufferedOutputStream in some cases.

Closing the decorator will result in closing the underlying stream which I want to avoid.

My question is so : Can I safely let the decorator unclosed and let the calling method manage the underlying stream release ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorating classes usually do not open system resources (like an operating system file-handle) that must be closed to prevent resource leakage. The given `OutputStream` parameter must be closed (because it is probably associated with an open system resource), but as you mention, this is the responsibility of the caller.

But if you do not close the decorating class, you must take care of method calls that normally take place in the `close()` method. In case of [`BufferedOutputStream`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.java) you can see that `flush()` is called in the super class [`FilterOutputStream`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/io/FilterOutputStream.java) `close()` method.

To accommodate these missing method calls, create a separate `NonClosingBufferedOutputStream` class that extends `BufferedOutputStream` that contains a modified version of the `close()` method from the `FilterOutputStream` (simply comment out the line `out.close();`). You can now use this class as a normal `Closeable` and avoid warnings from your IDE/compiler.

I was going to recommend using the [`CloseShieldOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CloseShieldOutputStream.html) from Apache commons-io, but looking at the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/output/CloseShieldOutputStream.java?view=markup), it appears that `flush()` is not called in the `close()` method. Despite this shortcoming, replacing the underlying outputstream with a [`ClosedOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/ClosedOutputStream.html) does appear to be a good idea: it will show programming mistakes much sooner.

Note that for other decorating classes like the `GZIPOutputStream`, other methods besides `flush()` could be appropriate. In `GZIPOutputStream`'s case, creating a `NonClosingGZIPOutputStream` class with a modified `close()` method that calls [`finish()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html#finish%28%29) could do the trick.